# Why can we multiply by breaking up the factors as sums in different ways?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

My friend and I were discussing some mathematical philosophy and how the number systems were created when we reached a question. Why can we multiply two different numbers like this?

Say we had to multiply $13\times 34$. One may break this up like $(10+3)\times (30+4)$. Applying distributive property here will give us the answer of 442. We can also choose to multiply this as $(6+7)\times (22+12)$. Intuitively, we can hypothesize that this should give us the same answer as $13\times 34$. How can we prove that our answer will be equal regardless of how we break up the numbers?

Comment: This will depend wildly on how you have _defined_ multiplication in the first place, and which axioms you're willing you let your proof rely on.

Comment: Is this a stupid question? Or is it ok to ask this.... I honestly can't tell

Comment: You can do this because the distributive property works and is inviolate. Now why the universe (or our brains) work this way? Who knows?

Comment: It's not a dumb question. Investigating structures where this isn't the case is a part of abstract algebra. If you take your question seriously you will be able to find out exactly what rules (in this algebraic structure) allow you to make these leaps.

Comment: Thanks for the comforting reply Mr. Mason. I've been thinking about these questions and I think I am going insane sometimes lol.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your age/education level? Asking this kind of questions (just gradually more and more difficult) is actually how you do science. One day you can learn for instance that $2+2=4$ only if you can prove that and even later that with proper assumptions it is possible that $2+2\neq4$. Just one example - questioning *obvious* thing that two lines can be parallel (have no common points), have one common point (crossing) or are the same line lead to an entirely new branch of non-euclidean geometry.

Comment: @Dude156, actually a very good question - and something that was very much at the forefront of maths around 1900, I believe. You could with advantage read P R Halmos 'Naive Set Theory', where the natural numbers, addition and multiplication are treated at a very fundamental level.

Comment: To those, who voted as off-topic - you need to understand, that OP most probably doesn't have enough background to even understand what you're asking. Yet this is a perfectly valid question. By putting on hold you may discourage OP from further research. For the time just assume (as I do), that OP has some very basic level of math skills, maybe only recently learned about things like distributive property.

Comment: Oh, no,no, no,no!  Re-open this!  It was an incrediable insightful and reasonable question.  And the OP did indeed express thoughts and confusion perfectly well.

Comment: If you can add what sort of foundation you want to build answers from, I think we can probably re-open this.  These sorts of questions tend not to have clear easy answers, but if they are framed with respect to a mindset (such as what does "prove" mean to you, or "why can we"), then that can often frame an answer.  For example, my answer is worthless if you wanted a simple answer that covered natural numbers, but if you want to dive into the question of "what is area anyways?" then it's a place to start.

Comment: It's a great question, and very insightful... just really tricky to answer in the format prescribed by Stack Exchange without some help in crafting the question properly.

Comment: "...without some help in crafting the question properly"  I think part of one of these "What's it all about" questions is an implicit "How would a beginner go about framing the question and what consequences are there in the different ways to look at it".  It's a bit unfair to expect a novice questioner to be expected to put it into the framework when conceptualizing potential frameworks *is* the question in the first place.  *All* answers from the "draw a picture" to peano postulates to ring axioms are *all* valid food for thought.

Comment: @fleablood I don't know about Math.SE, but WorldBuilding.SE has chosen to manage a "Sandbox" on their meta site where users can get help crafting questions.

Comment: I don't think the question *does* need to be crafted any better.  I think for the level of mathematics the OP and readers may have I think this *is* well crafted and general question.

Comment: @Ister I'm actually a junior in highschool- in Calc 2. I've just recently started to wonder about these topics, as I never learned the formal proofs for them. A few friends have mentioned set theory (here too @j4ndr2r53n) and abstract algebra.

Comment: You seem to be fond of this type of questions: why does the distributive law hold, [why does associativity holds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2948005/multiplying-by-10s-place-voodoo-why-is-30-times-50-15-times-100), etc.

Comment: Related question, this time about commutativity https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2697518/why-does-a-times-b-b-times-a-for-a-b-in-mathbbn/2697574#2697574

Comment: In other words is OP asking why the distributive property works?  Right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Formally, this is a property of [rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)).  Rings have a multiplication operation that distributes with respect to addition, meaning for any 3 numbers $a$ $b$ and $c$: $$a\cdot(b + c) = (a\cdot b) + (a\cdot c)$$  $$(b + c)\cdot a = (b\cdot a) + (c\cdot a)$$  The real numbers are a ring (they're actually a field, which is a special kind of ring), so that's half of your answer.

The other half is [Eric's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2978526/153899) which addresses the natural numbers.  Natural numbers are not a ring, but they *do* have a distributive property.

From a philosophical perspective, we could define anything we wanted, but what's interesting about this particular pattern is that it's so useful.  Nothing prevents me from making $x+\frac{3}{2}$ means a triple gainer with a twist, but outside of diving, that particular pattern isn't all that useful.  We tend to find that fields and rings show up rather often in physically meaningful scenarios.

Now from a philosophical perspective, it makes sense to point out that there are also lots of other really useful patterns that show up.  For example, if you look at how we define rotations, such as using [yaw, pitch, and roll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_principal_axes) to describe the orientation of an aircraft, those don't seem to add the way we want them to.  The rotations form a pattern known as a [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)), which doesn't even have a concept of addition at all!  They only have multiplication.  And by that I mean mathematicians decided to call the one operation in this pattern "multiplication" because its rules are a generalization of matrix multiplication.

We also have all sorts of oddball cases which may or may not actually be philosophically relevant.  For example, we can consider the [ordinal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number), which explore labeling objects as 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and so on.  Ordinals grapple with the concept of infinity, which generally means they've got some quirks.  One of the quirks of ordinals is that they are left distributive but *not* right distributive.  That means I can use the distributive property in $a\cdot(b + c)$ but *not* $(b + c)\cdot a$!  So that shows that we've come up with some really strange systems which look sane, but where the distributive law starts to get a little strange.  (For what it's worth, part of the reason this law acts so strange is that multiplication isn't commutative in ordinals: $2\cdot\omega \neq \omega\cdot 2$)

So in the end, what makes this distributive law so interesting philosophically is that real numbers and natural numbers seem to be *terribly* good at describing the world around us, and both of them have distributive properties.  But that doesn't mean that everything interesting has a distributive law, or even that the distributive law will make intuitive sense to you!  Now the question for why real numbers and natural numbers are so useful in reality is a really interesting philosophical question which has lead some people to argue that mathematics is the language upon which reality sits.

I say it sits on a turtle.  But who am I to judge?

Answer (score 57):

There are two ways I see to answer this question. One is from an axiomatic standpoint, where numbers are merely symbols on paper that are required to follow certain rules. The other uses the interpretation of multiplication as computing area. The former would take a good 5-10 pages to build up from the Peano axioms.

For the latter, you can draw a rectangle 13 units by 34 units. Break one side into 10 units and 3 units, and the other side into 30 units and 4 units. At this point, you should see that this decomposes the rectangle into four pieces, corresponding to the four terms you get from the distributive rule. The various was to compute $13 \cdot 34$ are all just ways to decompose the rectangle, and at the end of the day they all compute the same number: the area of the rectangle.

Comment: But would that be a proof? Or would it just be intuition? Idk, i've seen multiplication defined wildly differently. Some folks use multiplication as repeated addition, while others use it as area. What is the correct interpretation?

Comment: @Dude156: Defining multiplication as repeated addition is the axiomatic viewpoint I was referring to. And one can prove the distributive property from this definition, without any reference to area. However you should also see the definition of area, where the sides are whole numbers, as repeated addition. What the area interpretation offers is a way to see geometrically what's going on, and in my opinion, it greatly clarifies what's going on with the distributive property.

Comment: There is no one "correct"  interpretation.  But repeated addition only works for multiplying by integers.  And integer area *is* repeated addition ....

Comment: Proving *why* $13 \times 34=442$ is the same as proving $1+1=2$. It just proves how our undestanding of (mathematical) *language* works. It does not prove any empirical facts.

Comment: @Dude156: [My answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2978757/21820) should address the question in your comment. In particular, if you define multiplication as counting the number of objects in a rectangular array with the given number of rows and columns, then that is enough to understand distributivity of multiplication over addition of natural numbers. Absolutely no notion of area is needed. Furthermore, if you want a more fundamental approach, you can define multiplication as iterated iteration, as explained in the second half of my answer.

Comment: @Dude156 I agree that that is not a proof using that definition of multiplication but natural number multiplication can also be defined inductively as a statement of pure number theory. Did you mean given the inductive definition, how do I prove that if a = c + d, b = e + f, a = g + h, and b = i + j, then ce + cf + de + df = gi + gj + hi + hj? Did you mean how do I prove that using the definition by rectangles, multiplication can be well defined and that statement still holds?

Answer (score 36):

Well, that is literally what the distributive law tells you.  It tells you that $$(a+b)(c+d)=a(c+d)+b(c+d)=ac+ad+bc+bd$$ and so whenever you break up the two factors of a product as a sum, you can use the "pieces" to compute the product.

So what you are really asking for is a proof of the distributive law itself.  What constitutes a "proof" of such a basic fact depends heavily on what definitions of "numbers" and the operations on them that you are using (for some definitions, the distributive law is simply an axiom that you assume).  But here is an intuitive explanation that works for natural numbers (and this can be turned into a rigorous proof if you define arithmetic of natural numbers in terms of cardinalities of sets).

We want to prove that $(a+b)c=ac+bc$.  What does a product $xy$ of natural numbers mean?  Well, it means you draw a grid of dots with $x$ rows and $y$ columns, and count up the total number of dots.  So, to compute $(a+b)c$, you draw a grid with $a+b$ rows and $c$ columns.  Now we observe that we can split such a grid into two pieces: the top $a$ rows and the bottom $b$ rows.  The top $a$ rows form a grid with $a$ rows and $c$ columns, so they have $ac$ dots.  The bottom $b$ rows form a grid with $b$ rows and $c$ columns, so they have $bc$ dots.  In total, then, we have $ac+bc$ dots, so $(a+b)c=ac+bc$.

(In the computation of $(a+b)(c+d)$ above I used the distributive law in two different versions, one with the sum on the left side of the product and one with the sum on the right side of the product.  You can prove the version with the sum on the right side of the product in the same way (you just split up the columns instead of the rows), or you can deduce it from the other version using commutativity of multiplication.)

Comment: I'm personally fond of this explanation. When I was rather young, my older brother explained a bit about the distributive law to me.  I puzzled over it for a bit, and then came on my own to "ah - because if you draw a rectangular grid of dots, you can divide it into two smaller rectangles..."  This was exciting as a discovery of a generalized rule (more interesting than "obvious" ones like $a + 0 = a$) which justified why we can say things like $14 \times 2 = (10 \times 2) + (4 \times 2)$.  It definitely advanced my love of mathematics.

Comment: I confess I never had the "draw rectangles" realization  But I had the "paper bag" realization that $a + b$ is just putting $k=a+b$ into two different bags and $n(a + b)$ means we can $n$ copies of bags with $a$ items and $n$ copies of bags with $b$ items and we are clumping them together.  To me that was utterly concrete but I came to realize it was too many intricate steps away for others and too abstract.  .. I kind of wish I had a breaking rectangle moment.

Comment: This can also be formalized if your formalization "defines" $a \cdot b$ to be the cardinality of the Cartesian product $\{ 1, \ldots, a \} \times \{ 1, \ldots, b \}$ and similarly $a + b$ is the cardinality of the disjoint union $\{ 1, \ldots, a \} \sqcup \{ 1, \ldots, b \} = (\{ 1 \} \times \{ 1, \ldots, a \}) \cup (\{ 2 \} \times \{ 1, \ldots, b \})$, and then you prove for any finite sets $A$ and $B$, $|A \times B| = |A| \cdot |B|$ and $|A \sqcup B| = |A| + |B|$, prove (or define) two finite sets have equal cardinality if there is a bijection between them, etc.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: I suppose you would know what you are doing, but your comment would be misleading to students. If you define just the notion of equinumerosity, then you do not have actual cardinalities without picking a canonical representative (such as von Neumann ordinals). Even for finite cardinalities, you first have to prove that you can in fact find some natural $n$ such that $\{1..n\}$ is in bijection with $\{1..a\} \times \{1..b\}$, before you can define $a·b$ the way you said. But you cannot prove that without induction, so it is very much more involved than your comment suggests.

Comment: *for some definitions, the distributive law is simply an axiom that you assume* --- but then you would still have to prove that there *exists* a well-defined operation satisfying these axioms.

Comment: @user21820 In the formalization I was thinking of, the definition of cardinality of a finite set would be the length of a list of the elements, where the list covers all elements and has no duplicates.  (Then you do have to prove any two such lists have the same length, which is somewhat involved to do formally but is similar to a standard proof that two bases of a finite-dimensional vector space have the same size.  And I admit the intended formalization is not within ZFC, but more built on top of a type-theoretic foundation.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler: The natural interpretation of your last comment seems to yield a circularity, because you effectively need to assume at least as much as what you seem to be getting. Type-theoretic or not, you need the type of natural numbers with inductive properties, and the sheer complexity of the justification of the validity of the definitions makes it quite circular from both the philosophical and pedagogical viewpoint. It is similar to why ZFC cannot explain the axioms for PA even though it certainly proves the existence of a model of PA.

Answer (score 9):

The simplest and historical answer is that we observed that certain things in the world can be counted, in the sense that we can put them in a line and label each one with their position in the line, and that these positions satisfy certain empirical facts, and hence we invented [axioms to capture these facts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Equivalent_axiomatizations). I specifically single out the axioms in that linked section (discrete ordered semi-ring axioms plus induction), rather than the other more commonly known axiomatization of PA, for two reasons.

Firstly, the ring axioms have been observed or proven to hold for a very wide variety of structures, so it is no surprise that people invent them, and they include distributivity of multiplication over addition.

Secondly, that specific axiomatization I linked to accurately captures our empirical knowledge of counting numbers. For example, from our understanding of spatial motions (translations and rotations) we readily grasp that addition is commutative: $a+b$ is the total count of $a$ objects followed by $b$ objects in one line, which is the same as $b+a$ by looking at the line from the other side. Similarly for the commutativity of multiplication: $a·b$ is the total count of a rectangular array of $a$ times $b$ objects, which is equal to $b·a$ by rotating the array by $90$ degrees. And distributivity ($a·(b+c) = a·b+a·c$) is clear by splitting the array. Associativity is also intuitive.

Note that the above axioms are sufficient for us to recover general distributivity of the form you are using: Observe that $(a+b)·c = c·(a+b) = c·a+c·b = a·c+b·c$ by commutativity and distributivity. Thus $(a+b)·(c+d) = (a+b)·c + (a+b)·d = (a·c+b·c) + (a·d+b·d)$, and the order of addition in the last expression does not matter by associativity.

---

There is a more complicated answer, that also goes a significant way to explaining why counting numbers are the way they are. If you have an operator $f$ on some collection $S$ that can be iterated (i.e. $f : S \to S$), then you can define $f^0 = \text{id}_S$ and $f^1 = f$, and define $f^{m+n} = f^m \circ f^n$ and $f^{m·n} = (f^m)^n$ for every counting numbers $m,n$. The last definition is valid because (by induction) $f^m$ is an operator on $S$ that can be iterated. Then (again by induction), you can actually prove the basic properties of $+,·$. For example:

**Associativity of $+$**

Take any naturals $k,m,n$. Then $f^{k+(m+n)} = f^k \circ ( f^m \circ f^n ) = ( f^k \circ f^m ) \circ f^n = f^{(k+m)+n}$. Here we are using the fact that function composition is associative, which is a core reason for almost every instance of associativity in mathematics.

**Commutativity of $+$**

First we show that $f^{m+1} = f^{1+m}$ for every natural $m$. $f^{0+1} = f^0 \circ f = f = f$ $\circ f^0 = f^{1+0}$ by definition. For any natural $n$ such that $f^{n+1} = f^{1+n}$, we also have $f^{(n+1)+1} = f^{n+1} \circ f = f^{1+n} \circ f$ $= f^{(1+n)+1} = f^{1+(n+1)}$. Therefore by induction we are done.

Now take any natural $m$. Then $f^{m+0} = f^m \circ f^0 = f^m$ $= f^0 \circ f^m = f^{0+m}$. And for any natural $n$ such that $f^{m+n} = f^{n+m}$, we also have $f^{m+(n+1)} = f^{(m+n)+1} = f^{m+n} \circ f = f^{n+m} \circ f$ $= f^{(n+m)+1} = f^{n+(m+1)}$ $= f^n \circ f^{m+1} = f^n \circ f^{1+m}$ $= f^{n+(1+m)} = f^{(n+1)+m}$. Therefore by induction we are done.

As you can see from the above proofs, induction is enough for us to bootstrap from very rudimentary notions of iteration to obtain addition and its properties. We can do the same for multiplication. But it should be clear that this was not how the axioms were originally invented.

Comment: Good answer, but your second half uses notation and concepts that a high schooler isn't going to be familiar with. That's definitely university level maths.

Comment: @TamCoton: Well, the mathematics used is accessible to any high-school student who is sufficiently interested. Yes it's more complicated, but that is the best way to explain why the natural numbers are a very naturally arising structure rather than an incidental one.

Comment: A high schooler probably isn't going to know that f: S -> S means a function mapping every member of a set to another member of that set, nor are they going to know what to search to find that out. I suspect that id_S and ∘ are also likely to be confusing.

Comment: @TamCoton: Actually, in many countries such notation is taught and used regularly in high-school. And, of course, when you read something on the internet and find unfamiliar terms, Google is just a few clicks away...

Comment: @TamCoton: For reference, The Free Dictionary gives a definition of "[operator](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Mathematical+operator)" in Mathematics as "A function, especially one from a set to itself, such as differentiation of a differentiable function or rotation of a vector.". Googling either "id_S" or "id function" immediately brings up [Wikipedia's article on identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function). Likewise Googling "∘" brings up [Wikipedia's article on function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition).

Answer (score 6):

The "reason" it works is because in this universe quantities stay the same no matter how we group or arrange them.  Therefore because things don't magically appear and disappear we can count them.  And if we wanted to combine things by counting one group and then another group and combing them with another we can add them.

Thus we no $10 + 3 = 7+ 6 = 13$ are consistent ways of grouping and identifying values.

And we can do multiple adding to define multiplication. So $6 +6 + 6+6 =6\times 4 = 24$.  And as it quantities don't change when we group them then  $n(a + b) = \underbrace{(a+b)+... + (a+b)}_{n} = \underbrace{a + a...+a}_{n} + \underbrace{b + b...+b}_{n}=n\times a + n\times b$.

That is the way the world works.

And that is what we teach children.

But what kind of unimaginative simpleton cares about how the real world works?  Certainly not mathematicians.

Math is modeling and systemizing.

There are two standards:

1)  Axiomatic definitions.  The definition is a *field*, $F$ includes the axiom that for any $a,b,c \in F$ that $a(b + c) = ab + ac$.  That is the algebrists saying "I don't care why this is true in the real world, but it is this way in *my* world because I say it is."

2) Construction:  Develop the concept of natural numbers via the Peano Postulates and defining the idea of a first element $0$ and the ability to find a unique successor and a few basic axioms.  ... And then prove distribution.  In essence it is the same as how the real works, except we have defined the concept of *number* purely and abstractly, and not by giving Fred a bunch of apples.

This is the constructionist way of saying "I've extracted the pure essence of the real world into consistent abstract concepts".

Comment: Actually you don't even need reordering if you do it the other way round: $n(a+b)=\underbrace{n+\dots+n}_{a+b} = \underbrace{n+\dots+n}_a+\underbrace{n+\dots+n}_b = na+nb$.

Comment: True... but I was hiding the issue that for the definition $n\times a= (a + a + a+....+a)$ that $a$ need not be an integer.

Comment: In the other case, $n$ does not need to be an integer. And it also works for ordinals, where your version doesn't (because for ordinals, addition is not commutative).

Comment: Perhaps.  But then we are no longing in the real world where we are giving apples to Fred.  Thing is we can do this because multiplication distributes.  But why multiplicate distributes depends on... how we systemize our definitions and axioms.

Comment: OK, let's say we give 3 apples and then 5 apples to Fred, so $n=\text{Apple}$, $a=3$ and $b=5$. Fits my version perfectly.

Comment: Apple(1/2 + 2) = (Apple + Apple +... )1/2 times plus (Apple + Apple + ... ) 2 times doesn't work. You cant add something to itself a 1/2 time.  And $Apple\times k$ means $k$ Apples is not intuitively defined as clearly as all that....

Answer (score 3):

> How can we prove that our answer will be equal regardless of how we break up the numbers?

I may be not getting the gist of your question, other answers seem deep; but on some (shallowish) level you can proceed as follows.

If you have $A$ and $B$ and you choose $a$ and $b$ *freely*, then

$$A \equiv a+(A-a)$$
$$B \equiv b+(B-b)$$

<sub>Note I use "$\equiv$" symbol that is stronger than "$=$"; see [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1845410/331040) (its part named "definitions vs. equations or conditions") to get the difference. In the above expressions I used "$\equiv$" to emphasize they are true regardless of $a$ and $b$ (compare $A=A+b$ which may or may not be true (depending on $b$), hence only "$=$", not "$\equiv$").</sub>

In your example $A=13$ and $B=34$; initially you *choose* $a=10$ and $b=30$ and you *calculate* $(A-a)=3$ and $B-b=4$. Whatever numbers you choose for $a$ and $b$, your answer is expressed as

$$W(A,B,a,b) \equiv (a+(A-a))\times(b+(B-b)) \tag{*}$$

Now use

$$x-y \equiv x+(-1)\times y$$ to turn subtraction into addition; and use distributive property to get rid of the parentheses one by one. You don't want to cancel out $a$ and $-a$ right away, this would be trivial (as if you didn't break up the number); instead apply distributive property first in the same way you did with your numbers, observe that some expressions cancel out *eventually*. The outcome is:

$$W(A,B,a,b) \equiv A \times B \tag{**}$$

I don't know if this is what you asked for. Still *on some level* it shows that the answer (i.e. $W$) for fixed $A$ and $B$ is equal (i.e. the same) regardless of how we break up the numbers (i.e. regardless of what $a$ and $b$ we choose).

---

Formally for all this to work $\times$ and $+$ must denote some operations (with certain properties) that you can perform on members of some set (a set $A$, $B$, $a$, $b$, $0$, $1$ and $-1$ must belong to). It all comes to the concept of a ring [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2978736/331040) has already introduced. It's a ring with unity. The concept requires $0$, $1$ and $-1$ to be somewhat special:

$$0+x \equiv x$$
$$1 \times x \equiv x$$
$$1+(-1)=0$$

Plus (in our case) there is commutativity of $+$ and $\times$. If you go from (*) to (**) step by step and in a formal way then you will notice you need to use almost all these properties.

Answer (score 0):

For any natural numbers $a$ and $b$ and for any two ordered quadruplets of natural numbers (c, d, e, f) and (g, h, i, j) where $a = c + d$; $b = e + f$; $a = g + h$ and $b = i + j$, $(c + d)(e + f) = (g + h)(i + j)$ can be proven as follows.

$(c + d)(e + f) = ab = (g + h)(i + j)$

This question can also be interpreted as follows: how can I prove that $ce + ef + de + df = gi + gj + hi + hj?$

This is how to do it. It is a theorem that for any natural numbers $k$, $l$, $m$, $n$, $(k + l)(m + n) = km + kn + lm + ln$ so

$ce + cf + de + df = (c + d)(e + f) = ab = (g + h)(i + j) = gi + gj + hi + hj$